# How to center image in 2 column tabular when one side is Verbatim?

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I am having hard time finding the correct way to typeset this: I need to have code as verbatim on one side of the page, and show the output (an image) on the right side of the page.

I have tried using minipage, but that did not work well. I am now trying using a table with 2 columns. I put the verbatim text in the left column, then the image in the right column. The problem is that the alignment is not coming out right. I tried all the tricks I know about which are `\raisebox{-.5\height}` or using `m` for column specification.

Here is the output from a MWE:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'd like it to show up as follows (This was drawn manually using cut/paste) with the help of Visio and paint.exe

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the code (using demo option for Graphics so it works as is)

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}%
\usepackage[margin={2cm}]{geometry}%
\usepackage{array}%for m option

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[c]{|p{4in}|p{3in}|}\hline
%   \begin{tabular}{|p{4in}|m{3in}|}\hline    %also tried this, same problem
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]
Clear["Global`*"];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
sys = TransferFunctionModel[1/(s^2 + 2/10 s + 1), s];

yStep = Assuming[t > 0, 
  Simplify@OutputResponse[sys, UnitStep[t], t]];
yImpulse = Simplify@OutputResponse[sys,DiracDelta[t],t];
p = Grid[{
   {Plot[Evaluate@{yStep, yImpulse}, {t, 0, 50},
     PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {-0.8, 2.0}},
     Frame -> True,
     FrameLabel -> {{"y(t)", None}, 
                   {t, "step and impulse reponse"}},
     GridLines -> Automatic,
     GridLinesStyle -> Dashed,
     ImageSize -> {300, 300},
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Black},
     AspectRatio -> 1]
    },
   {
    Row[{"step response=", Re@yStep}]
    },
   {Row[{"impulse response=", Re@yImpulse}]}
   }, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> True]

yStep

{1 - E^(-t/10) Cos[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10] 
  - (
  E^(-t/10) Sin[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10])/(3 Sqrt[11])}

yImpulse

{(10 E^(-t/10) HeavisideTheta[t] 
  Sin[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10])/(3 Sqrt[11])}
\end{Verbatim}
&
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3in,height=3in]{whatever}}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

TexLive 2013, Linux

Comment: If you use `\raisebox{-\height}{...}` instead of `\raisebox{-.5\height}{...}` it seems to work better.

Comment: @PeterGrill I tried your suggestion, I do not see any difference? screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0i0ij.png)  (using Miktex on windows now) `\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=3in,height=3in]{whatever}}`

Comment: And which is the desired alignment?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Ok, will make a quick sketch, please give me a second

Comment: Did you try `\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{4in}|m{3in}|}` *without* the `\raisebox`? This gives you vertically centred objects.

Comment: @Nasser No need. Sorry. I didn't read your image in which you explained the desired positioning. I've provided an answer below in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `m{<length>}` column type for *both* columns:

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}%
\usepackage[margin={2cm}]{geometry}%
\usepackage{array}%for m option

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{4in}|m{3in}|}\hline
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]
Clear["Global`*"];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
sys = TransferFunctionModel[1/(s^2 + 2/10 s + 1), s];

yStep = Assuming[t > 0, 
  Simplify@OutputResponse[sys, UnitStep[t], t]];
yImpulse = Simplify@OutputResponse[sys,DiracDelta[t],t];
p = Grid[{
   {Plot[Evaluate@{yStep, yImpulse}, {t, 0, 50},
     PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {-0.8, 2.0}},
     Frame -> True,
     FrameLabel -> {{"y(t)", None}, 
                   {t, "step and impulse reponse"}},
     GridLines -> Automatic,
     GridLinesStyle -> Dashed,
     ImageSize -> {300, 300},
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Black},
     AspectRatio -> 1]
    },
   {
    Row[{"step response=", Re@yStep}]
    },
   {Row[{"impulse response=", Re@yImpulse}]}
   }, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> True]

yStep

{1 - E^(-t/10) Cos[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10] 
  - (
  E^(-t/10) Sin[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10])/(3 Sqrt[11])}

yImpulse

{(10 E^(-t/10) HeavisideTheta[t] 
  Sin[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10])/(3 Sqrt[11])}
\end{Verbatim}
&
\includegraphics[width=3in,height=3in]{whatever}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Fine tuning (if required) can be achieved with a `\raisebox`.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea one must use `m` for both columns, examples I saw just used 'm' for the column which has the image. Is this because one side is Verbatim in this case? Sometimes, I will have normal text in the left side as well (mised with some Verbatim). Will that still work? Will try it. I just did. Yes, it seems to work with normal text as well! This is great. Thank you

Comment: @Nasser Yes, as you noticed yourself, it works with regular text as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using the `verbatimbox` package.  While I left the columns as `p` type, one could use `c` type just as easily.

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}%
%\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}%
\usepackage[margin={2cm}]{geometry}%
\usepackage{array}%for m option

\begin{document}

\begin{verbbox}[\small]
Clear["Global`*"];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
sys = TransferFunctionModel[1/(s^2 + 2/10 s + 1), s];

yStep = Assuming[t > 0, 
  Simplify@OutputResponse[sys, UnitStep[t], t]];
yImpulse = Simplify@OutputResponse[sys,DiracDelta[t],t];
p = Grid[{
   {Plot[Evaluate@{yStep, yImpulse}, {t, 0, 50},
     PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {-0.8, 2.0}},
     Frame -> True,
     FrameLabel -> {{"y(t)", None}, 
                   {t, "step and impulse reponse"}},
     GridLines -> Automatic,
     GridLinesStyle -> Dashed,
     ImageSize -> {300, 300},
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Black},
     AspectRatio -> 1]
    },
   {
    Row[{"step response=", Re@yStep}]
    },
   {Row[{"impulse response=", Re@yImpulse}]}
   }, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> True]

yStep

{1 - E^(-t/10) Cos[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10] 
  - (
  E^(-t/10) Sin[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10])/(3 Sqrt[11])}

yImpulse

{(10 E^(-t/10) HeavisideTheta[t] 
  Sin[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10])/(3 Sqrt[11])}
\end{verbbox}
\begin{tabular}[c]{|p{4in}|p{3in}|}\hline
\theverbbox&
\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\savedverbbox-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3in,height=3in]{whatever}}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, interesting solution, I did not know about verbatimbox package.