# Code listing inside of tabu environment

Tags: listings, verbatim, tabu

I'm trying to insert a small code listing into a `tabu` table, however I'm unable to build a PDF.

The code I'm trying to use (well- a simplified form of it) is as follows:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....

%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{listings} % code listings
\usepackage{tabu} % for tables

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{X|X}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    myFunction() {
      do.Something();
    }
  \end{lstlisting}
  & This does something
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

And here are the errors in the build log:

```
D:/mwe.tex:22: Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \lst@next. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing } inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing \endgroup inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing \endgroup inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing \endgroup inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing } inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \lst@next. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing } inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing \endgroup inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing \endgroup inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing \endgroup inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing } inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing $ inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing } inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing } inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \lst@next. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing } inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing \endgroup inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing \endgroup inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing \endgroup inserted. [\end{tabu}]
D:/mwe.tex:22: Missing } inserted. [\end{tabu}]
```

When the listing is outside of the `tabu` environment, everything works as expected. Using a different table environment, such as `tabular`, produces the listing inside of a table.

Is there an issue with my Tex code? Does `tabu` not support code listings? Or have I missed something glaringly obvious? I've only been using LaTeX for a handful of days, so forgive me if that's the case!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you took the code in the linked question and added your own text to yield a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass{}` (`\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) and the appropriate packages that *illustrates* the problem . While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem, instead of spending time to first reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to use `tabu*` when you have verbatim material. Also, I'd suggest you use `\lstinline` (otherwise I think you would have to use a `\parbox`).

Comment: I've updated the question with a better example of what I'm working with.

Comment: @PeterGrill, Changing to `tabu*` AND `lstinline` works, however limits me to single-line code listings. I'd like to have a multi-line snippet in the table - sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: If you use `tabu` it isn't necessary to load `array` package, because `tabu` loads `array` internally.

Comment: See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179422/how-to-center-image-in-2-column-tabular-when-one-side-is-verbatim/179442#179442, using the `verbatimbox` package.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `tabu` doesn't support `listings` even in the `tabu*` environment.

However, I found that `pythontex` works:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....

%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{pythontex} % code listings
\usepackage{tabu} % for tables

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu*}{X|X}
  \begin{pygments}{c}
    myFunction() {
      do.Something();
    }
  \end{pygments}
  & This does something
\end{tabu*}

\end{document}
```

One has to run

```
pdflatex <filename>
pythontex <filename>
pdflatex <filename>
```

and then the output is

[image]